# conditionalPanel in multiple dynamic tabs creation

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny, tabs

I'm developing a shiny app where the user will be able to describe the room occupancy of multiple houses. The main idea of the code is to input the number of houses (`inputId = 'n_houses'`), i.e. the number of tabs in the `mainPanel` is equal to the number of houses inputed. Each house tab should be connected to a different `sidebarPanel`, i.e. when accessing the house tab in the `mainPanel`, the correspondent `sidebarPanel` is displayed. In the `sidebarPanel`, the number of rooms (`inputId = 'n_rooms'`) of the correspondent house tab is inputed. Finally, each room is inputed with an occupancy value (`inputId = 'occup'`), that can be either 'liv' (living room) or 'dorm' (dormitory).
Each `mainPanel` tab should display the occupancy of all its correspondent rooms.

A simple example of the **inputs** follows:

1. **n_houses = 2** (two houses)
2. **n_rooms1 = 2** (two rooms in the first house) - 2.a. **occup11 = 'liv'** (living room); 2.b. **occup12 = 'dorm'** (dormitory)
3. **n_rooms2 = 3** (three rooms in the second house) - 3.a. **occup21 = 'dorm'** (dormitory); 3.b. **occup22 = 'liv'** (living room); 3.c. **occup23 = 'dorm'** (dormitory)
   Ps.: it sums a total of 5 room occupancies.

Then, the **outputs** should be:

- mainPanel tab 1 (house 1): 'Results for house 1: liv dorm dorm'
- mainPanel tab 2 (house 2): 'Results for house 2: liv dorm'

The code chunk below shows my last efforts to solve this issue.

---

```
# shiny user interface
ui = shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    headerPanel(
      h1('ROOMS OCCUPANCY', align = 'center')
    ),
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(
        inputId = 'n_rooms',
        label = 'Choose the number of rooms in the correspondet house:',
        min = 2, max = 5, step = 1, value = 3
      ),
      uiOutput('rooms')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      sliderInput(
        inputId = 'n_houses', 
        label = 'Choose the number of houses:',
        min = 1, max = 20, step = 1, value = 1
      ),
      uiOutput('houses')
    )
  )
)

# auxiliar functions to shiny server
# generate room tab panel
GenRoomTab = function(ind_room, ind_house) {
  panel = tabPanel(
    title = paste('Room', ind_room),
    value = paste0(ind_house, ind_room),
    radioButtons(
      inputId = paste0('occup', ind_house, ind_room),
      label = 'Room occupancy:',
      choices = list('Living room' = paste0('liv', ind_house, ind_room),
                     'Dormitory' = paste0('dorm', ind_house, ind_room)),
      selected = paste0('liv', ind_house, ind_room)
    )
  )
  return(panel)
}
# generate room tabset panel
GenRoomTabset = function(ind_house, n_rooms) {
  tab_panels = lapply(1:n_rooms, GenRoomTab, ind_house)
  tabset_panel = do.call(tabsetPanel, tab_panels)
  condition_panel = list(condition = paste('input.tabselected ==', ind_house), tabset_panel)
  return(condition_panel)
}
# generate house tab panel
GenHouseTab = function(ind_house) {
  panel = tabPanel(
    title = paste('House', ind_house),
    value = ind_house,
    h4(paste('Results for house', ind_house, ':'))
  )
  return(panel)
}
# generate summary tab panel
GenSummTab = function() {
  panel = tabPanel(
    title = 'Summary'
  )
  return(list(panel))
}

# shiny server
server = shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
    # define room tabset panels
    output$rooms = renderUI({
      room_tabsets = do.call(GenRoomTabset, list(1:input$n_houses, input$n_rooms))
      do.call(conditionalPanel, room_tabsets)
    })
    # define house tab panels
    output$houses = renderUI({
      house_tab_panels = lapply(1:input$n_houses, GenHouseTab)
      summ_tab_panel = GenSummTab()
      tab_panels = c(list(type = 'tab', id = 'tabselected'),
                     house_tab_panels, summ_tab_panel)
      do.call(tabsetPanel, tab_panels)
    })
  }
)

# associate ui to server
```

### shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

When I run this code the following warning message shows up:

*Warning: Error in radioButtons: The 'selected' argument must be of length 1
  105: stop
  104: radioButtons
  100: FUN [/home/rodox/git/giz/app/app.r#29]
   99: lapply
   98:  [/home/rodox/git/giz/app/app.r#44]
   96: renderUI [/home/rodox/git/giz/app/app.r#71]
   95: func
   82: origRenderFunc
   81: output$rooms
    1: runApp*

I think it is related to `selected = paste0('liv', ind_house, ind_room)`, inside function `GenRoomTab()`. The `GenRoomTab()` is applied within `lapply(1:n_rooms, GenRoomTab, ind_house)`, inside the function `GenRoomTabset()`. However it seems strange to me, since `ind_house` is a vector as well as `ind_room`.

Another difficulty that I have is to display the occupancy of all the rooms into the correspondent house tab.

I've been trying to solve this for a while, but couldn't solve it... **I hope someone can save me!**

Comment: Welcome to SO! "I'm stuck" isn't really a helpful description of your problem.  What doesn't work?  What error messages do you get, if any?  What is the desired outcome?  Although the OP's question was different to yours, my answer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62341353/saving-dynamic-ui-to-global-r-workspace/62342118#62342118) demonstrates one way of generating a dynamic UI with elements that vary depending on a user's input.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback @Limey, my description was really short and not helpful. I edited the post and hopefully you'll have a better overview of the problem. I'll take a look at the post you recommended and keep you updated if a found a solution.